# Macro to create email and save it in public folder

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I want to create an email and instead of sending it, saving it to a folder.

Like saving to the Drafts folder, but a folder I choose.

I am creating the email like this:

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objOutlookMsg
    ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
    Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("TO")
    objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

    If DisplayMsg Then
        .Display
    Else
        .Save     
    End If
End With
```

This saves the email in the Drafts folder. Is it possible to choose a different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move objOutlookMsg to a folder named, for example, notDraft.

```
Sub moveTo_NotDraft_Folder()

    Dim objOutlookMsg As mailItem
    Dim objOutlookRecip As recipient

    Dim oNs As Namespace
    Dim inbox As folder
    Dim targetFolder As folder

    Set oNs = GetNamespace("mapi")
    Set inbox = oNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set targetFolder = inbox.Folders("notDraft")

    Set objOutlookMsg = CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With objOutlookMsg
        ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
        Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("TO")
        objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo
        .Save
        .Move targetFolder
    End With

    Set ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = targetFolder

ExitRoutine:

    Set objOutlookMsg = Nothing
    Set objOutlookRecip = Nothing
    Set oNs = Nothing
    Set inbox = Nothing
    Set targetFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```